# Make dynamic array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have following one static array

```
$times = array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
```

now i want to become dynamic (according to start time and close_time), it means i have start_time="09:00" and 
close_time="21:00",then array should become like following result.

```
$times = array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30".......,"20:30","21:00");
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more info, please see How to Ask and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

You can do like below example: -

```
$startTime  = new DateTime('2019-01-15 09:00');  //or you can pass time only. example - new DateTime('09:00');
$endTime    = new DateTime('2019-01-15 21:00'); //or you can pass time only. example - new DateTime('21:00');
$timeStep   = 30;
$timeArray  = array();

while($startTime <= $endTime)
{
    $timeArray[] = $startTime->format('H:i');
    $startTime->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$timeStep.'M'));
}

echo json_encode($timeArray);
```

**Output**

```
["09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30","13:00","13:30","14:00","14:30","15:00","15:30","16:00","16:30","17:00","17:30","18:00","18:30","19:00","19:30","20:00","20:30","21:00"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) to iterate through the times into an array:

```
$start_time = new DateTime('09:00');
$close_time = new DateTime('21:00');
$periods = new DatePeriod($start_time, new DateInterval('PT30M'), $close_time);
foreach ($periods as $period) {
    $times[] = $period->format('H:i');
}
// DatePeriod excludes the end time
$times[] = $close_time->format('H:i');
print_r($times);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 09:00 [1] => 09:30 [2] => 10:00 [3] => 10:30
        [4] => 11:00 [5] => 11:30 [6] => 12:00 [7] => 12:30
        [8] => 13:00 [9] => 13:30 [10] => 14:00 [11] => 14:30
        [12] => 15:00 [13] => 15:30 [14] => 16:00 [15] => 16:30
        [16] => 17:00 [17] => 17:30 [18] => 18:00 [19] => 18:30
        [20] => 19:00 [21] => 19:30 [22] => 20:00 [23] => 20:30
        [24] => 21:00
      )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cCTHb)